# Can SQL insert multiple row get infiltrate while process

Tags: mysql, sql

**Test.id** is **primary key** and **auto increment**

while I insert using this SQL

```
 INSERT INTO Test (id,name) values (null, "a") , (null, "b") , (null, "c")
```

if someone use

```
 INSERT INTO Test (id,name) values (null, "d")
```

while process just finish insert "a" 

will result be (id,name) 

 `(1,a) , (2,b) , (3,c) , (4,d)`
 
 or 
 `(1,a) , (2,d) , (3,b) , (4,c)`

 or other

Comment: May it depend on the kind of table? MyISAM or InnoDB? I read that `An INSERT statement that acts on a partitioned table using a storage engine such as MyISAM that employs table-level locks locks all partitions of the table. This does not occur with tables using storage engines such as InnoDB that employ row-level locking.` in http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most SQL engines do not support [Concurrent Inserts](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/concurrent-inserts.html) by default. However, some of them give you the option to allow that in the configuration.

On its own, an insert is an [atomic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomicity_%28database_systems%29) statement. What it means is that the DB will be locked before the insert, and will only be unlocked AFTER the insert has either completed, or failed.

For example, if I write these statements and execute them at the same time

```
INSERT INTO Test VALUES(null, 'a'), (null, 'b'), (null, 'c'), (null, 'd')
```

and

```
INSERT INTO Test VALUES(null, 'e'), (null, 'f')
```

What essentially happens is a [race condition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition). So my output can be either

```
1 a, 2 b, 3 c, 4 d, 5 e, 6 f
```

or

```
1 e, 2 f, 3 a, 4 b, 5 c, 6 d
```

I can even use an INSERT SELECT statement and it will lock the database until the statement is done completely.

```
INSERT INTO Test select * from test2
```

So, in your case, once the first query starts running, the next query WILL have to wait, and therefore, the output will be

```
(1,a) , (2,b) , (3,c) , (4,d)
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot predict what is going to happen - either choice is possible, depending on who has executed it earlier.

When you created AUTO_INCREMENT column, it only guaranteed that it will be unique - there is no guarantee what exactly it is going to be, and there is no guarantee that it will not contain holes, which may be created by rolled back transactions.